# Get Facebook Page age and country restrictions via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I read Facebook Graph API [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page). There is no way I found to get Facebook Page age and country restrictions. Is there any way to get Facebook Page age and country restrictions via Graph API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no field in the reference, so there is no way to get that information with the API.